# How do I keep checkbox checked after refresh

Tags: php, laravel

0

am trying to check checkbox after i search categories. but its errors
explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given

```
 <input id="subCats-{{$s->id}}" name="category[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $s->id }}"   
@if (request()->category != "" && in_array($s->id,explode(',', request()->category)))
checked
@endif
>
```

and am having problem with

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="level" value="0" id="lvl-0"
                                @if (request()->level == 0)
                            checked
                            @endif
```

it's always is checked because if i don't requests its null and it's thinks that its 0 i tried (request()->level === 0) but it's still don't works.

others with level are working

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="level" value="1" id="lvl-1"
                                @if (request()->level == 1)
                            checked
                            @endif
     <input type="checkbox" name="level" value="2" id="lvl-2"
                                @if (request()->level == 2)
                            checked
                            @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your

```php
in_array($s->id,explode(',', request()->category)))
```

explode generates an array from a string, but your "request()->category might not give you a string, it is already an array.

so maybe its working with this:

```php
in_array($s->id, request()->category ?? []))
```

Comment: btw. I tried to reformat your question, because it's not readable at all. Unfortunately the edit queue is full and the change will not be reviewed now.

Comment: am getting error 
in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, null given

Comment: then you have to add a default value, if the function returning null. I edit my answer.

Comment: thank u it's works : ) do u know how can i fix level problem to ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that template engine. But if === don't work, you need to find a way to differentiate between int 0 and null.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's being checked regardless of the if statement. So this might work:

```
<input type="checkbox" :checked="{{ request()->level === 0 }}" />
```

Comment: thanks for response. it's don't working (

Comment: Try after removing ":"

Comment: now its always checked

Comment: maybe fix your html. after adding some line breaks, I see that some of your `<input>` tags missing the closing `/>`

Comment: i have closing i just didn't add it to question...

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem with the `null` / `0`, you can add to your condition a check to make sure the value is not null like this:

```
@if (request()->level == 0 && !is_null(request()->level))
    checked
@endif
```